# CSS selector for element with two classes not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to style these elements, and the element with two classes can't be style different than the one with one class. I've tried to select it with `.red.balls` also, but it doesn't work.

```css
.ballsAll {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 14%;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.balls {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='ballsAll'>
  <p>
    <span class='balls'>22</span>
    <span class='balls red'>11</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Both the selectors `.red` and `.balls` have specifcity and so the selector that is defined last in the CSS file gets precedence (and applies to both).

Comment: `.red.balls` works https://jsfiddle.net/jjkvasyt/

Comment: If `.red.balls` doesn't work, something else is wrong and what you have given does not reflect your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Declare .balls before .red, Like this:

```
.ballsAll {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 14%;
}
.balls {
  background-color: white;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}


<div class='ballsAll'>
  <p>
    <span class='balls'>22</span>
    <span class='balls red'>11</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```css
.ballsAll {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 14%;
}
.red.balls {
  background-color: red;
}
.balls {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='ballsAll'>
  <p>
    <span class='balls'>22</span>
    <span class='balls red'>11</span>
  </p>
</div>
```